# Rails 3 nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, nested-forms

I have a problem about the nested forms, which I've survey for some possible solutions ([Nested form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form), [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)) but still have no idea to implement it.

My question is totally based on the solutions above, so please read it if you need :)

Now, my question is: 
If i want to add/edit "only one" **Question(and it's Answers)** per page after I "create/edit" a **Survey** how could I make it?

In other words, there is only one **Question**(but could have dynamic numbers of **Answers**) fields, in the "create/edit" **Survey** page.

And how to make
 
**add another question**, 
 
**edit previous question** or 
 
**remove current question** 
functions.

I've try to solve this by 2 ways, one is using javascript to hide the previous question each time I add a new one, but in this schema, I can't make my way to edit the existed question.

Another is using Ajax, but ... I have no idea with it.